# Android: What is the difference between viewholder and viewgroup?

Tags: android, layout, viewgroup

please give a detailed explanation about the differences between the viewholder and viewgroup and if they both are similar or used for similar purposes then please tell me the advantages of one over the other.

Comment: You should definitly first search yourself for the two keywords. There are bunch of information material in the net.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are different things for different purposes.

What they have in common is that they both have references to `View`s.

A [`ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) is a parent class of all layouts. It is basically the `Composite` when applying the [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) to create view hierarchies.

A [View Holder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) is not a specific class but just a pattern you can apply to minimize the number of `findViewById()` calls by caching the results in a holder object. `findViewById()` is really a DOM tree lookup which is relatively costly in terms of runtime performance.

Comment: Off-topic: How costly is to loop in a `View` collection as `ViewGroup` holds its children?